# Как написать с помощью RxJava2 простую итерацию как в примере

Tags: android, rxjava, rxandroid, rxjava2

Вот есть такой метод который я использую для того, чтоб при получении ответа с сервера сделать парс сразу в енам

```
@JsonCreator
    public static eTaxCode getTaxCodeByIdOrDefault(int iTaxCode)
    {
        eTaxCode result = DEFAULT;

        for (eTaxCode tmp : eTaxCode.values())
        {
            if (tmp.getTaxCodeId() == iTaxCode)
            {
                result = tmp;
                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Все просто я беру значения енама прохожу по каждому и если есть совпадение, то возвращаю это значение если нет, то возвращаю дефолтное значение.

Теперь хочу сделать тоже самое с помощью RxJava2 (знаю, что возможно это не тот случай и что стандартный подход очень крутой, но интересно понять как это сделать)

Я пробовал сделать как то так(на таком же примере)

```
@JsonCreator
    public static eSingDetails getSingDetails(int iSignDtls)
    {
        eSingDetails result = DEFAULT;

        Observable.fromArray(eSingDetails.values())//
                  .filter(iValue -> iValue.getSignDtls() == iSignDtls)//
                  .isEmpty()//
                  .subscribe(iIsEmpty ->
                  {
                      if (iIsEmpty)
                      {

                      }
                      else
                      {

                      }
                  });

        return result;
    }
```

Но все равно не то, что то получается...

Как это правильно сделать?

Comment: Rx тут совсем не подходит, поэтому у вас и не получается. Это больше задача для stream api.

Comment: @eugeneek Я несколько раз слышал, что есть разработчики которые пишут полностью реактивную апплекацию(правда еще не встречал таких апплекаций)  и вот мне интересно как был бы написан этот метод если использовать полностью реактивный подход

Comment: Ну если просто ради интереса, то метод может возвращать не сразу `eSingDetails`, а обсервабл, который обёрнут вокруг него: `Observable<eSingDetails>` (либо Flowable, Single и т.д. в зависимости от задачи), чтобы можно было использовать дальше в цепочке Rx, либо просто подписаться в нужном месте. Но я бы так делать не стал. Любая технология - это лишь инструмент, и пользоваться им нужно в предназначенных для него местах. А гвозди, как известно, можно и микроскопом забивать.

Answer (score 1):

Сама функция может выглядеть так:

```
public static Single<eTaxCode> getTaxCodeByIdOrDefault(int iTaxCode)
{
   return Flowable.fromIterable(eTaxCode.values())
                  .takeUntil(value -> {
                     return value.getTaxCodeId() == iTaxCode;
                  })
                  .filter(value -> value.getTaxCodeId() == iTaxCode)
                  .single(DEFAULT);
}
```

А вызов соответственно так:

```
getTaxCodeByIdOrDefault(taxCodeId)
   .subscribe(taxCode -> {
      // что-то делаем
   });
```

---

*Документация по оператору [takeUntil](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takeuntil.html)*

*Документация по [Single](http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html)*

Comment: Я так понимаю, что оператор `takeUntil` здесь нужен только для того, чтоб остановить выполнение если нужный элемент будет найден, верно?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, именно

Comment: Да, но как вернуть не Single а обьект? Так как в моем коде Rx не везде и удобнее если будет возвращатся обьект , а не Single

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, использование Rx подразумевается то, что сущности в обёртках в виде потоков, на получение которых нужно подписываться. Я думаю, что если вам нужно получить результат синхронно, то реактивный подход применять не нужно